# Close a word document that is already open

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check whether a specific word document is open or not. If open, then close it and first then reopen again and if not then just open it.

The problem is that I always get a Bad file name 4160 error when it tries to close the document.

Would anyone plz tell me where exactly is the problem in my code.

Thank u in advance.

```
        Dim wdApp As Object
        Dim myDoc As Word.Document

        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

        If IsFileOpen("C:\Letters\TemporaryLetter.docx") Then
            wdApp.Documents("C:\Letters\TemporaryLetter.docx").Close
        End If

        With wdApp
            .Visible = True
            .WindowState = 2
        End With

        Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Letters\TemporaryLetter.docx")
```

Comment: Try closing with correction `wdApp.Documents("TemporaryLetter").Close`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the function "IsFileOpen" that you are calling I"m guessing it requires the short name of the file (e.g. "TemporaryLetter.docx") not the full path??  Try:

```
If IsFileOpen("TemporaryLetter.docx") Then
    wdApp.Documents("TemporaryLetter.docx").Close
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Set myDoc = word.Documents.Open ("C:\Letters\TemporaryLetter.docx")

If IsFileOpen(mydoc) Then
        mydoc.Close(False //Here if you want to save your document or not)
End If
```